# Jog java interpreter to return the console output as string

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, interpreter

Im trying to make a java interpreter for iphone, however the [library](https://code.google.com/p/jog-interpreter/) which i am using only prints the console output to the NSLog/printf console. I want it to return a std::string which i can convert to NSString and display in a UITextView. Has this been done before? either capture the console log (it needs to be accepted by appstore) or change the source adding a method to return a string with the buffer.

Comment: what kind of string? a `char *` or a `wchar_t *` or a `std::string` or a `NSString`??

Comment: conversion is possible so it doesnt matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C Standard Input and Output Library is you friend.

You should be aware that NSLog output to stderr and printf use stdout. So depending on your needs you can redirect only one or both if u needs all output.

Let's say we will write all the stream into a file (two in our example for stdout and sdterr), then when we are done we close the files, then you can display them simply using the files keep into document directory.

```
 // get user directory
    NSArray *allPaths       = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDIR  = [allPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pathForLog    = [documentsDIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"logFile.txt"];
    NSString *pathForError  = [documentsDIR stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"errorFile.txt"];

 // redirect the stream
   freopen([pathForError cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding],"w", stderr); // NSLog
   freopen([pathForLog cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], "w", stdout); // printf

 // your log stuff
   printf("i am a robot\n");
   NSLog(@"And i do bip bipbip biiiip");

 // when you are done, close the stream
    fclose (stdout);
    fclose (stderr);

 // and retrieve your data, as NSString object (or whatever you want)
    NSString* dataLog = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: pathForLog
                                                  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                     error: nil];

    NSString* errorLog = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: pathForError
                                                   encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                      error: nil];
```